# Is there a systematic way to generate such matrices?

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

Given a positive integer $n > 3$, is there a way (if any) to generate a matrix $M \in \mathbb{F}_2^{n \times n}$ that satisfies the following three conditions:

1. $M$ is invertible, more precisely, $M \in \text{SL}(n,\mathbb{F}_2)$
2. $M$ has an almost equal number of $0$ and $1$ entries. That is, $$\| N_M(1) - N_M(0) \| \leq 1$$ where $N_M(1)$ denotes the number of $1$ entries in $M$.
3. For every $3 \times 3$-sized blocks (thanks for pointing out this in comments) $M_s$ of $M$, $$\|N_{M_s}(1) - N_{M_s}(0)\| \leq 1$$

For example, I think, when $n = 4$, a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

satisfies all the $3$ requirements listed above. However, I am not sure if such matrices exist for some larger $n > 4$ and I am curious.

---

**Motivation**

I want to use such matrices to encode binary messages. Invertibility ensures one can decode such messages. Up to size $8 \times 8$ is enough for practical uses, I think.

Comment: It may be worthwile checking for condition (3) the $4\times 4$ case on a computer with a brute-force algorithm: you have $\binom43^2\times 2^{16}\approx 10^6$ cases to check, and if there aren't then there won't be for any $n>3$.

Comment: In your example, the submatrix made of rows $(1,2,4)$ and columns $(1,3,4)$ and the submatrix made of rows $(1,2,4)$ and columns $(1,2,4)$ have $N(0)=6$.

Comment: By submatrices here I mean submatrices with consecutive rows/columns selected.

Comment: That is a detail worth mentioning.

Comment: In the case of consecutive lines and rows, use the term "blocks" instead of "submatrices".

Comment: I would have written $N_1 (M)$ instead.  Or, even better, $\#_1 (M)$

Comment: If you're going to use $\ M\ $ to encode binary sequences, presumably you'd want $\ M\ $ to be invertible *modulo* $2$ in condition $1$ (a stronger requirement than merely being invertible over the rationals)?  Or are you going to allow the encoded messages to be non-binary?